# MySQL won't Insert JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Something strange is happening here, normally i wouldn't have an issue, or maybe i am just tired. But MySQL won't accept my syntax to insert JSON into a table.

```
foreach ($newArray as $k => $v) {
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `achievements` WHERE `achieveID`=".$v['ID']." LIMIT 1";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($default, $query)) {
        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row_cnt > 0 ? $parse = false : $parse = true;
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }   
    $v['required'] == 'None' ? $req = $v['required'] : $req = json_encode($v['required'], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    if($parse) {                        
        $result = mysqli_query($default, "INSERT INTO `achievements` VALUES (NULL, '".$v['cat']."', '".$v['ID']."', '".$v['title']."', '".$v['type']."', '".$v['factionD']."', '".$v['factionE']."', '".$v['text']."', '".$v['doneText']."', '".$v['points']."', '".$v['number']."', ".$req.", '".$v['rewards']."')") or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($default));
    }
}
```

My code inserts everything else in fine, and does other rows but when it gets to a row that required json data (ie when $v['required'] does not equal to none) it does not insert it and gives me an error.

```
Unable to execute query. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"0":"Into the Undertow","1":"Darkwater Abyss","2":"Primal Powers and Triton's Dr' at line 1
```

The JSON (from the json encode)

```
{"0":"Into the Undertow","1":"Darkwater Abyss","2":"Primal Powers and Triton's Dread","3":"Stirring Interstellar Waves"}
```

It seems like the double quotes are causing the issues?

EDIT

Ive re-wrote my code! Thanks for the tips!

```
$insert = $default->prepare("INSERT INTO achievements (catID, achieveID, achieveName, achieveType, factionDominion, factionExiles, achieveText, achieveCText, achievePoints, achieveNum, achieveReq, achieveRew) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insert->bind_param("iissiissiiss", $cat, $id, $title, $type, $factionD, $factionE, $text, $doneText, $points, $number, $required, $rewards);

foreach ($newArray as $k => $v) {
    $query = "SELECT id FROM achievements WHERE achieveID=".$v['ID']." LIMIT 1";
    if ($result = $default->query($query)) {
        $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
        $row_cnt > 0 ? $parse = false : $parse = true;
    }   
    $v['required'] == 'None' ? $req = $v['required'] : $req = json_encode($v['required'], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    if($parse) {    
        $cat = $v['cat'];
        $id = $v['ID'];
        $title = $v['title'];
        $type = $v['type'];
        $factionD = $v['factionD'];
        $factionE = $v['factionE'];
        $text = $v['text'];
        $doneText = $v['doneText'];
        $points = $v['points'];
        $number = $v['number'];
        $required = $req;
        $rewards = $v['rewards'];   
        $insert->execute();
    }
}
$default->close();
```

And its working perfectly, it was really fast too, it added over 2000 rows in a few seconds! I am pretty sure there is a cleaner way to write it but first time using prepare!

Comment: use prpared statements. It is much more safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here `'".$v['number']."', ".$req.",`

The `$req` variable holds string and you need to wrap it in single quote as

`'".$v['number']."', '".$req."',`

The best option would be to use prepare statement to avoid these errors and sql injection.

Comment: Thank you, i just found that myself lol... after rechecking my code for the 100th time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes and special characters. Check out the [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp)